# How to target text between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

**Update Below**

I'm trying to target the output of [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) and add some custom events and styling to module elements.

Codemirror displays the following code as such.

```
<div><module type="content"></module><span>can contain other data</span></div>
```

In the DOM it is rendered between a series of spans.

```
<pre>      
    <span class="cm-tag">&lt;div&gt;&lt;module</span> 
    <span class="cm-attribute">type</span>
    =
    <span class="cm-string">"content"</span>
    <span class="cm-tag">&gt;&lt;/module&gt;&lt;span&gt;</span>
    can contain other data
    <span class="cm-tag">&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</pre>
```

The issue I'm having is trying to add a yellow background to the whole module element, but because the "=" part is between two elements, I'm not sure how to target it with a selector.

This is what I have right now, but because it does not include the text between the elements, there are gaps in the background color.

```
    $('.cm-tag:contains("<module")').each(function () {
        var $closingElement;
        $(this).nextAll().each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == "></module>") {
                $closingElement = $(this).next();
                return false;
            }
        });
        var $module =$(this).add($(this).nextUntil($closingElement));

        $module.addClass('module');
    });
```

Anyone have suggestion/ideas about how to accomplish this?

**Update**
I was able to get part way there by using the wrapAll jquery method, but the visible result still isn't quite right. Now the spaces and equal characters are removed from the wrapped element and placed after it.

```
<modulename"content"id"1234"/> = =

function hilightModules() {
    $('.cm-tag:contains("<module")').each(function() {
        var $module = $(this);

        $(this).nextAll().each(function() {
            $module = $module.add($(this));

            // closing element
            if ($(this).hasClass('cm-tag')) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $module.wrapAll('<span class="module" />').click(function() {
            // Do stuff                    
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: what happens if you set the style for the <pre> element?

Comment: why not setting bg-color directly for `<pre>` tag? sounds that there is a problem with the output, what kind of nesting elements is this?

Comment: I've updated the example's. There can be other standard HTML markup on the same line, so I don't want to change the color on the whole <pre> tag.

Answer (score 1):

For adding click handlers to content text, your best bet is to just register a mousedown handler on the CodeMirror wrapper element, and, in that handler, determine whether the thing clicked is what you are looking for. Content elements may change at any time, and you don't want to register tons of handlers.

As for highlighting things, I'd recommend an overlay mode (see http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html for an example), rather than trying to do it with DOM munging (for the reasons listed above).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Raminson said, you could target the `<pre>` tag to make the background span the entire section. Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/CSzny/

Comment: Problem is the pre tag is per line and each line could contain other standard HTML markup that I don't want highlighted in this way. I'll update the example to show this.